# Are Koopa the Quick times constant?

Tags: super-mario-64

When racing Koopa the Quick in Super Mario 64, is the time of Koopa the Quick always the same? If so, what times do you have to beat to get the star?

Comment: According to the [Super Mario 64 Speedrun Wiki](https://sm64-speedrun.fandom.com/wiki/Bob-omb_Battlefield_(BoB)#Footrace_with_Koopa_the_Quick), once you win the race Koopa will start running at a faster speed. The earlier you finish the race, the faster Koopa's time will be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a bit of testing, they are not 100% consistent, but it's close every time.

In the Bob-Omb Battlefield stage, there's a bit of RNG because Koopa needs to jump over rolling cannonballs and the time will not be exact every time. With that in mind, I got between 1'30"0 and 1'32"0 for the N64 version, and no less than 1'28"00 for the DS version.

In the Tiny-Huge Island stage, I got around 0'23"0 for the N64 version, and I ALWAYS got 0'26"00 for the DS version.